# AWS IOT - Can you modify parameters in Provisioning Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I have a device that is misbehaving. It is connected to AWS IoT Core as a thing. It connected using AWS Just In Time Provisioning (JITP).

So this device was working fine until after certificate rotation. Once the new certificate was in place, my understanding is that the device will just start to send packets using the new certificate etc. And when the first one arrives, the JITP mechanism will recognise the valid device credentials and create the thing certificate in AWS IoT.

However, what I am seeing for this one rogue device (testThing) is that the DeviceRegister event fails. I've created a CloudTrail to capture the raw API access. And luckily, it's pretty clear what it's objecting to:

```
"eventSource": "iot.amazonaws.com",
"eventName": "RegisterThing",
"errorCode": "InvalidRequestException",
"errorMessage": "Invalid registration template. Cannot resolve reference value: {Ref=AWS::IoT::Certificate::Country}",
"parameters": {
    "AWS::IoT::Certificate::CommonName": "testThingC\\=NZ",
    "AWS::IoT::Certificate::Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYY",
    "AWS::IoT::Certificate::SerialNumber": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXYYYYYYYYYYY"
}
```

It appears that one of the parameters in the provisioning template is not available. The common name is set to "testThingC\=NZ", instead of "testThing"... And the common name is missing from the parameter list entirely. Looks like it got appended to the common name somehow.

Can anyone shed light on how this could have come about? Thanks!